# Get unique session ID/key on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, client-server, clientid

I'm almost sure what I'm looking for exists, but I didn't finding on Microsoft documentation nor here.

I just want to get an unique ID (a string or a number, I don't really mind) from a client in ASP.NET 4.5, on the server side. I want this ID linked to a session, so different for each system that would connect to my server (like multiple computers or same client with different browsers), but the same if a user open multiple tabs on the same browser on my server.

I already looked on:

- `System.Web.UI.Page.ClientID`: It is the name of the control (so always "__Page").
- `System.Web.UI.Page.UniqueID`: It returns the same.
- `Session.LCID`: I'm not sure to what it refers to, but it is the same if I connect to my server with different browsers.
- `Session.SessionID`: Change each time I refresh the page or open it in a new tab.
- `Request.AnonymousID`: Is null.

So all my attempts gave me an ID that changes everytime or never. Is there any way to get something from session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is in fact the `Session.SessionID`, however it comes with a caveat.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx):

> When using cookie-based session state, ASP.NET does not allocate storage for session data until the Session object is used. As a result, a new session ID is generated for each page request until the session object is accessed. If your application requires a static session ID for the entire session, you can either implement the Session_Start method in the application's Global.asax file and store data in the Session object to fix the session ID, or you can use code in another part of your application to explicitly store data in the Session object.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using REMOTE_ADDR / REMOTE_HOST values from ServerVariables collection. These would have same values even if the user is using multiple browsers and uses different sessions from the same machine. Note that REMOTE_HOST might not always have a value.
References :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I tried this method: there is a problem when multiple machines connect through a same VPN service that manage their IP addresses: they have the same IP address.